# neo4j/Everyman - how to pass in a string parameter?

Tags: php, neo4j, cypher

Am attempting to pass in a string value for a parameter as follows:

```
$names = array( 'test0', 'test1', 'test2' );   
$q0 = "match (n:label0 { id: '{param0}'}) return n";
foreach( $names as $name )
{
    $q1 = new Everyman\Neo4j\Cypher\Query( $connection, $q0, array( 'param0' => $name );
    $r = $q1->getResultSet();

    echo( var_dump( $r ));
}
```

Running this code gives me 3 `var_dump` outputs with no result set. If I substitute in the actual param value (instead of getting it from the array) I get the expected result set. Similarly if I enter the query in using the Neo4j-shell I get the value(s) that I expect.

So what am I doing wrong? I'm sure I'm using this incorrectly but I'm not clear how.

I can put the variable in directly and the query works also (though this negates any possible gain from using parameters anywhere else in the query). It's just doing it via a parameter that seems problematic.

---

EDIT:

- neo4j v2.1.4

Comment: Just guessing, lose the single quotes aroung {param0}?

Comment: Tried that. No change. Also tried passing in the quotes, using double quotes and backticks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$q0 = "match (n:label0 { id: {param0}}) return n";
```

what happens if you do this? Remove the single quotes?

You can also rewrite your query to:

and pass in the whole string array as a param

```
$names = array( 'test0', 'test1', 'test2' );   
$q0 = "match (n:label0) WHERE n.id IN {param0} return n"; 
$q1 = new Everyman\Neo4j\Cypher\Query( $connection, $q0, array( 'param0' => $names );
```

make also sure to `create index on :label0(name)`

Comment: FWIW: removing the quotes doesn't work (for me). Using the `IN {param}` works.